# How to send MULTIPART_FORM_DATA in UTF-8 format FROM Rest template

Tags: spring

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

its not working for me.can anyone help me.

Comment: Please enhance your question: what are you trying to achieve? Where's the call? What error do you receive? What to you expect?

Comment: Also, this is a good read on how to ask questions and get solutions (and not waste time of others that clicked through to your question): http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html